# Regular expression lookfroward greedy

Tags: javascript, regex

Help me please to make a regular expression for strings including numbers.

I have to parse the `1234`, `1234567`, but i don't have to find something like `1232:` or `1233s`.

I tried this

`/[0-9]*/`

but this regulars takes matches `1233` from string `1233s`, but in case doesn't.

Comment: /^[0-9]+$/ would hit just-number-containing strings. add a dot to range for decimals

Answer (score 2):

Try negative lookahead:

```
/^\d+(?!:)$/
```

Description:

- `\d+` matches one and more numbers
- `(?!:)` not followed by a colon.

Looking and the question more closely, and providing that `:` is not the only character you want to prevent from matching (thank you MikeW), you should be good to go with simpler regexp:

```
/^\d+$/
```

Comment: Wouldn't `/^\d+$/` be enough?

Comment: @MikeW Looks like I totally overthought this! Of course, you are right. Thank you very match!

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `parseInt` function instead of regex:

```
parseInt("1233s")
1233
parseInt("1232:")
1232
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
 /[\d]+/
```

I hope this will be ok

Comment: This will fail for precisely the same reason as the OP's original regex fails: it matches any sequence of digits in the string, regardless of what's around them.